# usings sprites with Jquery multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-sprites

so I am am using sprites to show blank checkboxes and on each click I want to have it so it goes from blank, to green check mark, to grey check mark, to an X. Link is to sprite image.

http://s23.postimg.org/fz6v0ts6z/sprite.png

Anyways I am currently only able to select the box once and it turns the red X off but I can't change any it to the check marks... Any help would be great!

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <title></title>
    <style>

#catNav li a {
    display: block; width:25px; height: 25px; text-indent: -9999px; background: url(images/sprite.png)no-repeat;
}

#catNav li a#list-one-button {
    background-position: -25px -25px;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton1 a#list-one-button {
    background-position: -25px -75px
}
#catNav li a#list-two-button {
    background-position: -25px -75px;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton2 a#list-two-button {
    background-position: -25px -25px;
}
#catNav li a#list-three-button {
    background-position: -25px -125px;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton3 a#list-three-button {
    background-position: -25px -125px;
    }
#catNav li a#list-four-button {
    background-position: -25px -175px;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton4 a#list-four-button {
    background-position: -25px -175px;
    }

    </style>


    <script>
    $(function(){

        $("#catNav li a").click(function(){
            $("#catNav li").removeClass("activeBlankButton1");
            $(this).parent().addClass("activeBlankButton2");
        });

        // $("#catNav li a").click(function(){
        //  $("#catNav li").removeClass("activeBlankButton");
        //  $(this).parent().addClass("activeBlankButton2");
        // });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <ul id="catNav">
            <li class="activeBlankButton1"><a id="list-one-button">blank</a></li>
            <li class="activeBlankButton2"><a id="list-two-button">X</a></li>
            <li class="activeBlankButton3"><a id="list-three-button">green</a></li>
            <li class="activeBlankButton4"><a id="list-four-button">grey</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over complicating your CSS which is making the logic in your javascript a little off.

I'd recommend removing the id specific styles to make it simpler:

```
#catNav li a {
    display: block; width:25px; height: 25px; text-indent: -9999px; background:         url(http://s23.postimg.org/fz6v0ts6z/sprite.png)no-repeat;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton1 a {
    background-position: -25px -75px
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton2 a {
    background-position: -25px -25px;
}
#catNav li.activeBlankButton3 a {
    background-position: -25px -125px;
    }
#catNav li.activeBlankButton4 a {
    background-position: -25px -175px;
}
```

From there you can have listeners for clicks on the different styles toggling them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul").on("click", ".activeBlankButton1", function(){
      $(this).removeClass("activeBlankButton1");
      $(this).addClass("activeBlankButton2");
   });
   $("ul").on("click", ".activeBlankButton2", function(){
      $(this).removeClass("activeBlankButton2");
      $(this).addClass("activeBlankButton3");
   });
   $("ul").on("click", ".activeBlankButton3", function(){
      $(this).removeClass("activeBlankButton3");
      $(this).addClass("activeBlankButton4");
   });
    $("ul").on("click", ".activeBlankButton4", function(){
      $(this).removeClass("activeBlankButton4");
      $(this).addClass("activeBlankButton1");
   });
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5T63/1/)

I will admit my jQuery here is not the most efficient but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah I over thought it I think!! I really appreciate it! jQuery and me aren't the best of friends... YET